# R Flexdashboard : Cant run in Shared Network Folder

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I am new to R Flexdashboard and I have encountered this problem with my flexdashboard R and I have spent some time solving but still unable to solve it. Might be just a silly mistake and hope you guys can help me with this.

I encounter this error when i shift my rmd file from desktop to my shared network folder:

> "Error: unexpected symbol in
>   "rmarkdown::run('S:/Project/Data/Sam\'s Projects/R Dashboard/Dashboard.Rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = FALSE), auto_reload = FALSE, dir = 'S:/Project/Data/Sam's"
>   Execution halted"

I did ensure that I have installed the required libraries. Anyone has any idea?

[image]

Comment: From what I can tell from your image tho:  on line 4, you have an additional `:` in `output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:`

Comment: Hello , thanks for your prompt reply. I look at sample codes from the rmarkdown website , they do have the same number of : . Please correct me if i am wrong. Ty very much

Comment: @FabianTan comment `Risk.R` and `Config.R` and see if it works

Comment: I tried , it doesnt work. Thank you

Comment: Hey guys , i found that after i remove the "runtime: shiny" it works. Anyone has any idea why? But i still want to be able to use shiny.

Comment: I also realise that it can only run when my rmd file is at the desktop and if my rmd file is at a shared network folder. It causes the same error.

Comment: @FabianTan try to remove the 's in Sam `S:/Project/Data/Sam\'s Projects/R`. Also make sure you have sufficient permissions over the Shared folder.

Comment: @FabianTan I can confrimed now that `'s` is your problem, `Error: unexpected symbol in "rmarkdown::run('C:/Users/ababaker.suliman/Documents/Abubaker\'s Project/test.Rmd', shiny_args = list(launch.browser = FALSE), auto_reload = FALSE, dir = 'C:/Users/ababaker.suliman/Documents/Ab"
Execution halted`

Comment: Thank you very much ! i will try to see if it works